# googleCast getMediaInfo() returning null value each time

Tags: java, android, chromecast

Currently, I'm trying to communicate with my receiver app and sender app (android, iOS both). 
I am just trying to fetch  getMediaInfo() but its returning null value each time. Can anyone please help me to resolve my issue.

**Note: For now I have implemented a queue mechanism at receiver app CAF v3 than facing this issue. I have also checked in the case of queue mechanism at sender app (android) than i am able to get all `getMediaInfo()` and its working fine.**

Please find my code snippet below:

```
@Override
        public void onMetadataUpdated() {
         MediaInfo mediaInfo =  getRemoteMediaClient().getMediaStatus().getMediaInfo();
        }
```

*While `getRemoteMediaClient().getMediaStatus()` is not null , but
`getRemoteMediaClient().getMediaStatus().getMediaInfo()` is returning always null value.*

Note: "Title" and "Image" is showing on TV which are connected to cast device and working fine with iOS.

iOS code are below:

```
[[[[GoogleCastManager mediaControlChannel] mediaStatus] mediaInformation] metadata]
```

If any one have a solution, then please suggest it to me.  I would be very thankful to you.

Thanks in advance.